# Solve the initial value problem for this inhomogeneous heat equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve this IVP for heat equation,
$$u_t-\frac{1}{4}u_{xx}=e^{-t}~~\text{ in }-\infty<x<\infty,~t>0,$$
$$u(x,0)=x^2.$$
By the superposition principle, the solution should equal to a particular solution + the general solution. I find one particular solution could be $-e^{-t}.$ Thus, we have $u(t,x)=v-e^{-t}$ where $v$ is the general solution.
Now we have 
$$v_t-\frac{1}{4}v_{xx}=0~~\text{ in }-\infty<x<\infty,~t>0,$$
$$v\Big|_{t=0}=x^2+e^{-t}.$$
I had trouble to solve the general solution. I think I could use heat kernel,
$$v=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}y^2~dy,$$
but I don't how to solve this since I am required to write the solution as a linear combination, $u=C_1f_1(t)g_1(x)+\cdots+C_nf_n(t)g_n(x)$, not in $\mathscr{E}rf[u]$.

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Why not solve the homogeneous equation by separation of variables?

Comment: @okrzysik Like how?

Comment: Have a go at googling "separation of variables heat equation"?

Comment: @okrzysik It seems to me that there will be a difficulty with traditional separation of variables since the domain is not bounded, so the spectrum of the Laplacian is not discrete. You can derive the heat kernel solution using the Fourier transform, which is analogous to the Fourier series approach, but it is still the heat kernel solution.

Comment: More on-topic: I think you can actually compute this heat kernel convolution explicitly. The $x^2$ part is essentially the variance of a Gaussian random variable (up to some constants), and the $e^{-t}$ part can be handled by adding the exponents and completing the square (so you again have a Gaussian integral, up to some constants)

Comment: @Ian: I did miss that and I agree, thanks!

Comment: @lan Agree but is Gaussian integral up to constants a linear combination?

Comment: You can just compute the integrals, then regroup terms to separate the homogeneous part and inhomogeneous part.

Answer (score 1):

So your $v$ is given by

$$v(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} e^{-(x-y)^2/t}(y^2+1) dy.$$

I am assuming your formula for the heat kernel is correct. I didn't carefully check the constants. I always lose track of the $2$ that differentiates between standard Brownian motion and the standard heat equation, so you should definitely check this yourself.

Anyway, the exponential corresponds to a Gaussian r.v. with mean $x$, so you want to modify things to get $(y-x)^2=y^2-2xy+x^2$ in there. Adding and subtracting:

$$v(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} e^{-(x-y)^2/t} ((y-x)^2+2xy-x^2+1) dy.$$

Factoring out constants:

$$v(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} \left ( \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-y)^2/t} (y-x)^2 dy + 2x \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-y)^2/t} y dy + (-x^2+1) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-y)^2/t} dy \right ).$$

Compute these integrals (each is now quite standard). Then subtract off $e^{-t}$ to get back to $u(x,t)$, and identify the homogeneous part and the inhomogeneous part.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use tools from tempered distribution. Then you need to recognise that $\forall T \in S(\mathbb{R})$ its fourier transformation has the property of $<\hat{T},\phi> = <T,\hat{\phi}> = \hat{\phi}(0) $ where S is Schwarz class function and $\phi$ is some test function.

The solution to your auxiliary problem is: $$v(x,t) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{t}}(x^2 + e^{-t})\ dx$$

edit: the general solution to the Heat Cauchy Problem, i.e. $u_t - u_{xx} = f$ & initial condition of $u_o$, is quite standard
$$ u(x,t) = K(x,t) \ast u_o + \int_0^t K(x, t-s) \ast f(x,s) \ ds$$
where $K(x,t)$ is your heat kernel.

Comment: I know this formula but I need to write $u$ as a linear combination. There shouldn't be integrals.

Comment: Then this is tricky. Before I go on, may I ask if your $x$ is on a real-line ($\mathbb{R}^1$) or is it on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: It's on real line.

Comment: I'm out of idea how to deal with that Kernel and it's 4 a.m. here. So before I go to bed, might I suggest a finite difference approximation for your problem? Hahahas sorry, I will see myself the way out.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_t-\frac{1}{4}u_{xx}=e^{-t}~~\text{ in }-\infty<x<\infty,~t>0,$$
$$u(x,0)=x^2.$$

An obvious particular solution is $-e^{-t}$ . Then change of function $u=v-e^{-t}$
$$v_t-\frac{1}{4}v_{xx}=0 \quad\text{with condition }\quad v(x,0)=x^2+1.$$

This form of boundary condition draw us to try a polynomial form of solution. With a general second degree polynomial of two variables, the method of identification of coefficients leads very easily to :
$$v(x,t)=x^2+1+\frac{1}{2}t$$
So, the solution of the problem is :
$$u(x,t)=x^2+1+\frac{1}{2}t-e^{-t}$$